# Visual Studio 2019 Comunity Browser Button not visible

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I just newly installed Visual Studio Comunity 2019, and I tried to start a new ASP.NET MVC project. However, I can't seem to find the Browser Button. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJgEx.jpg
I mean the one where you can choose with which Browser (IE, Chrome, Mozilla, etc) do you want to run your project. Does anyone know how to fix this.

I'm in Germany and Visual Studio is also in german.:D

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So, aparently I get this issue when I'm forking from a Repo from Github. If I close and reopen the Visual Studio after the fork, the problem is solved.

So far, It happend only with two repos. The thing is that I borrowed a new laptop and installed the Visual Studio 2019 on it. Never had this issue before on my old PC.

Feels good fixing your own issues. :D